# How can I disambiguate a type and a module with the same name?

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm trying to use Károly Lőrentey's [B-tree based `OrderedSet`](https://github.com/lorentey/BTree) in a project. However, I'm running into an issue where I can't declare an unqualified `OrderedSet<T>` because the name conflicts between Foundation's `NSOrderedSet` (imported as `OrderedSet` in Swift 3) and `BTree`'s `OrderedSet`.

```
let set = OrderedSet<Int>()
// error: 'OrderedSet' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
// Found this candidate: Foundation.OrderedSet:3:14
// Found this candidate: BTree.OrderedSet:12:15
```

To resolve this conflict, you would normally qualify the name, and that would give you `BTree.OrderedSet<T>`. However, the `BTree` module also contains a class named `BTree`. If I write `BTree.OrderedSet`, Swift thinks that I'm referring to a type named `OrderedSet` that is nested in the `BTree.BTree` type.

```
let set = BTree.OrderedSet<Int>()
// error: reference to generic type 'BTree' requires arguments in <...>
```

If I don't `import BTree`, I can't use the `BTree` name at all.

```
// no import BTree
let set = BTree.OrderedSet<Int>()
// error: use of undeclared type 'BTree'
```

How can I resolve this ambiguity between the `BTree` type and the `BTree` module?

Comment: This is a great question. Can you `typealias` one of them?

Comment: I can't "typealias away" one of them, typealiases can only create names (`OrderedSet` will remain a valid, if ambiguous, name for both types). But even to typealias one, I need to be able to refer to it...

Comment: Since I don't use Foundation in this project, I was able to unblock myself by removing `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` in the bridged header. However, that doesn't solve the general (and very real) problem.

Comment: Sounds like [a good bug to report](http://bugs.swift.org).

Comment: This bug has [already been reported](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-898). I started a thread on swift-evolution to find a design.

Comment: Is this truly a bug? I'm genuinely curious. Wouldn't you *not* want anything to clash namespaces--even if it came from Objective-C?

Comment: Seems to me that we haven't exhausted possibilities to disambiguate that case and that it would be unfortunate to declare it "by design" until then.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for the clarification @zneak

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The type can be disambiguated using the little-known `import (class|struct|func|protocol|enum) Module.Symbol` syntax.

```
import struct BTree.OrderedSet
```

From this point on, OrderedSet unambiguously refers to the one in BTree.

If this would still be ambiguous or sub-optimal in some files, you can create a Swift file to rename imports using typealiases:

```
// a.swift
import struct BTree.OrderedSet
typealias BTreeOrderedSet<T> = BTree.OrderedSet<T>
```

```
// b.swift
let foo = OrderedSet<Int>() // from Foundation
let bar = BTreeOrderedSet<Int>() // from BTree
```

There was a new syntax discussed for Swift 3, but it fell through.

Comment: Thanks! One can also use `protocol`, `enum`, i.e., all keywords that define types after the import to import only a specific type.

Comment: Can I `import BTree` after this? I mean I only want to avoid the conflict only one class but the rest of them are not conflict. If I use this to disambiguated import do I also need to change all other non-conflict class to this?

Comment: @SaintTail, I don’t know off the top of my head. Try it and report your results!

Comment: @zneak Doesn't seem to work . I need to add all the required classes the same way as the conflict one.

Comment: I imported a framework with a protocol that had the same argument type name as an existing type in my project. `typealias` solved this. Amazing!

Comment: But this only works if you don't require to use the `BTree` class as well within the same file. Since if you `import BTree` or `import class BTree.BTree` after the typealias, you are back at the start as then Swift will consider `BTree` to refer to the class again, not to the module, even if the typealias was above the second import.

Answer (score 5):

I renamed `OrderedSet` to `SortedSet` in the [Swift 3 version of `BTree`](https://github.com/lorentey/BTree/blob/swift3/Sources/SortedSet.swift), which should serve as a workaround while a possible language-level fix is being discussed/implemented.

Comment: I brought up the issue again on the mailing list a few minutes ago. Hopefully things get going.