# Swift - Can't use Namespace when Framework/Module with class with same name

Tags: swift, module, namespaces

**Environment**:

Swift >=2.3, Swift Framework in a Swift app

**SetUp:**

- A Swift dynamic framework with module name, let's say
  `APIService.framework`.
- It has a `public class APIService.swift` and it
  has static functions.
- It has another `public class Item.swift`.
- A swift application that usage `APIService.framework`
- App can work with the framework like `APIService.function()`
- App also has a `class Item.swift`

If App needs to refer Item class of framework it has to do `APIService.Item` but since APIService is a class inside the framework, compiler always try to look for a property inside APIService class rather than in the APIService Module, hence throws an error saying

```
'Item' is not a member type of 'APIService'
```

**Possible Solutions:**

- Change the framework's Module name to something other than class
  name.
- Change the class name to something other than the Module Name.
- Put a "Item" static property inside APIService class that points to
  Item class in framework.

All these are just workarounds, the real issue remains that compiler is not able to differentiate between Module name and class name. Do we have anything in Swift by which I can say `"Don't look into the ModuleName.swift, instead look into the whole Module"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's old problem with symbol name collisions in Swift because the compiler resolves names in the following priority order:

1. Local Declarations
2. Imported Declarations
3. Imported Modules

Your app's `Item` class name overrides the imported one from `APIService` module and `APIService` class name overrides its module name in your case so that you can't access to `APIService.Item` anymore.

The only solution is importing the framework to a clear namespace (module) without collisions, typealiasing and then reimport it into your app and to do that you can make a wrapper framework and link your third-party library in i.e.:

`Your App` -> `Wrapper Framework(typealias)` -> `Target Framework`.

Let's `APIService` framework has implementation:

**APIService.swift**

```swift
public class APIService {
    public static func test() {
        print("APIService")
    }
}

public class Item {
    public static func test() {
        print("APIService.Item")
    }
}
```

Make `Dependencies` framework, link it with `APIService` framework and add this file:

**Dependencies.swift**

```swift
import APIService

public typealias APIService_Item = Item
```

Now you can link `Dependencies` framework into your app (`APIService` is linked automatically) and import the libraries to your code:

**App.swift**

```swift
import Dependencies
import APIService

class Item {
    static func test() {
        print("App.Item")
    }
}

...

Item.test() // Prints: App.Item
APIService.test() // Prints: APIService
APIService_Item.test() // Prints: APIService.Item
```

Thus as you can see from the test we've got access to `APIService.Item` class.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38508385/2522077), it looks like you can directly import a single type from a module to get around this.

```
import class APIService.Item
```

Then you can refer to `Item` directly without confusion.

The `class`, `protocol`, `struct`, `enum` and `func` keywords (at least) work in this situation.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case. Xcode 14 ‍♂️  Error `Item` is not a member type of class `APIService.Item`. Still the question is "Do we have anything in Swift by which I can say "Don't look into the ModuleName.swift, instead look into the whole Module""