# 'JSONEncoder' / 'JSONDecoder' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Tags: ios, json, swift, encoder, decoder

I am getting following Error

[image]

I don't know why I am getting this, How can I resolve it?
Please Help!

**NOTE:** I am using **Xcode Version 9.3.1** and **Swift4**, 
I had tried to use **JSONCodable.JSONEncoder** and **JSONCodable.JSONDecoder** but it won't work.

**Here is Code:**

```
import Foundation
import JSONCodable

extension JSONEncoder {
    func encode(_ value: CGAffineTransform, key: String) {
        object[key] = NSValue(cgAffineTransform: value)
    }

    func encode(_ value: CGRect, key: String) {
        object[key] = NSValue(cgRect: value)
    }

    func encode(_ value: CGPoint, key: String) {
        object[key] = NSValue(cgPoint: value)
    }
}

extension JSONDecoder {

    func decode(_ key: String, type: Any.Type) throws -> NSValue {
        guard let value = get(key) else {
            throw JSONDecodableError.missingTypeError(key: key)
        }
        guard let compatible = value as? NSValue else {
            throw JSONDecodableError.incompatibleTypeError(key: key, elementType: type(of: value), expectedType: NSValue.self)
        }
        guard let objcType = String(validatingUTF8: compatible.objCType), objcType.contains("\(type)") else {
            throw JSONDecodableError.incompatibleTypeError(key: key, elementType: type(of: value), expectedType: type)
        }
        return compatible
    }

    func decode(_ key: String) throws -> CGAffineTransform {
        return try decode(key, type: CGAffineTransform.self).cgAffineTransformValue
    }

    func decode(_ key: String) throws -> CGRect {
        return try decode(key, type: CGRect.self).cgRectValue
    }

    func decode(_ key: String) throws -> CGPoint {
        return try decode(key, type: CGPoint.self).cgPointValue
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code as well

Comment: Please Check I had Updated The Question.

Comment: Why do you partially reinvent the wheel? All `CGAffineTransform`, `CGRect` and `CGPoint` conform to `Codable` and why do you use a third party library anyway?

Comment: @vadian I Downloaded this project from Github.

Comment: The built-in `Codable` protocol is certainly 100 times more efficient than the 2 year old library, with all respect for the developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `JSONCodable` also declares the `JSONEncoder`/`JSONDecoder` classes, so the compiler doesn't know which ones you want extend: the standard ones, or the ones from the library.

Telling to the compiler which class to extend by prefixing the class with the module name, should eliminate the ambiguity.

```
import Foundation
import JSONCodable

extension JSONCodable.JSONEncoder {
    // extension code
}

extension JSONCodable.JSONDecoder {
    // extension code
}
```

However that won't work for this particular library, as the library declares a protocol with the same name (`JSONCodable`). Thus, you need to explicitly import only the two classes from the module (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892621/how-can-i-disambiguate-a-type-and-a-module-with-the-same-name) for more details):

```
import Foundation
import class JSONCodable.JSONEncoder
import class JSONCodable.JSONDecoder

extension JSONCodable.JSONEncoder {
    // your code
}

extension JSONCodable.JSONDecoder {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error 'JSONEncoder' is not a member type of 'JSONCodable'

Comment: @KhushbuDesai updated answer, should now be workable.