# Swift migration: 'Notification' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context' in some places

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I'm making a migration from Swift 2.3 to Swift 5 with a lot of pain and well, I'm ending the migration but I'm still getting an error in some places of the code:

`Notification' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context`

I recieved before this error but now I'm getting this in places like

```
var notifications = [Notification]
self.notifications = (sql.execute() as NSArray) as! [Notification]
```

and

```
 func isAlreadyExists(notification: Notification) -> Bool {
```

I thought to change Notification name but the app is not mine and is big... very big and is not possible to do this and well, I don't know what to do.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Tried to do the same as suggested in [How can I disambiguate a type and a module with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892621/how-can-i-disambiguate-a-type-and-a-module-with-the-same-name) but doing "import (class|struct|func|protocol|enum) Module.Symbol" desn't works (I see where Notification is in the project but doesn't work ProjectName.class).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disambiguate a type and a module with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892621/how-can-i-disambiguate-a-type-and-a-module-with-the-same-name)

Comment: I tried that solution but doing "import (class|struct|func|protocol|enum) Module.Symbol" desn't works (I see where Notification is in the project but doesn't work ProjectName.class).

Comment: Then you need to rename it.

Comment: Why would anyone migrate _to_ Swift 4? Swift is at 5.6. Swift 4 is what you want to get away from.

Comment: Sorry I mistipped swift version. I'm actually migrating to Swift 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it worked by changing the class name and adding it to a file called `<Project_name>-Bridging-Header`.

Doing this I could call the class with `var example = <Project_name>.<className>`